Binary search comprehension problem. how can a '<' / '>' symbol be checking for strings?
My code works OK. The problem here is comprehension. I get that it splits and goes back and forward in the search.
What I don't get is how to give a descriptive explanation on what each code line is doing.
What mainly confuses me is that it has this comparison before re-running the function where it compares strings, target, and arr[middle], with the larger/smaller-than operator. How can that be checked if its an array of strings with single letters? I don't get it.


function search(arr, target, start = 0, end = arr.length - 1) {
  console.log(start, end)

  if (start > end) {
    console.log('Not found!');
    return -1;
  }

  const middle = Math.floor((start + end) / 2);

  if (arr[middle] === target) {
    console.log(`${target} Found at index ${middle}`);
    return middle;
  }

  if (arr[middle] > target) {
    return search(arr, target, start, middle - 1);
  }

  if (arr[middle] < target) {
    return search(arr, target, middle + 1, end);
  }
}

const arr = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'x', 'y', 'z'];
console.log(search(arr, 'b'));




Ok, Gemini bot already answered this explanation,:
"if (arr[middle] < target) { checks if the element at the middle index (arr[middle]) is lexicographically less than (comes alphabetically before) the target."

MDN is a really useful reference tool. The < and > (and related) operators work with strings because they have clearly-defined semantics when applied to strings, defined by the language specification.

Most programming languages are able to compare strings or individual characters with < and >. It is not really related to the binary search algorithm that is implemented here. An expression like "a" < "b" is valid, and is true.
